# Output from fully connected network in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

```
weights = {

# 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs

'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
`# 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs`

'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])), 

# fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])), 
 # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)



'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes])) 


}
```

In this code,the output from fully connected layer is given as 1024 but I cannot understand from which calculation this '1024' is generated and I cannot find any satisfactory answer from tensorflow documentation.And How this ouput size affects the prediction result.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number like 1024 is usually somewhat empirical, depending on the data and the goal.

In general, I think the question has too many ramifications to answer succinctly. I'll answer in the restricted and assumed context of the question: Convolutional nets. The kind of network you describe often have hidden layers with more nodes than the target number of classes (this is a classifier, right?).

In your case the last hidden layer has 1024 nodes, more than the 10 output classes. Is it necessary number? It depends on your data quantity, diversity, etc. This number does not mean much without a context and a goal.

The least we can usually be confident with: The number is higher than the output classes. Doing so, the network is able to store a "large" number of features to describe classes. The output layer then gets these many features as input, and computes combinations down to the expected number of classes.

Comment: Actually when I change this number result of classification changes.Some times when I increase this number,I get more efficiency sometimes not.So I cannot understand  particular which value should be used.

Comment: Changing the number will impact your results. Running several times too---keep in mind the stochastic process involved. Imagine you have a drape and want to spread it over your sofa. You want the drape to follow your sofa shape as well as possible, just by spreading it over the sofa and letting it cover. You can get good results, but there will be bumps and folds. ML is somewhat similar, that's why the terms like fitting, and overfitting. A lot of try and fail, guided by your experience and ingenuity. Beyond this analogy, check out online advices from Hinton on how to choose NN layers.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the 1024 is the dimension of the fully connected/hidden layer. wd1 has a fan out of to 1024 and then goes back to the 10 output classes. Hence as happens frequently in deep learning, the 1024 is not the result of a calculation, but is a hyperparameter.